# Warning while running lammps-daily on ubuntu 12.04 lts

Tags: 12.04

I get the following Warning while running lammps-daily on ubuntu 12.04 lts:

```
WARNING: OMP_NUM_THREADS environment is not set. (../comm.cpp:100)
```

using 1 OpenMP thread(s) per MPI task

After this, the cursor starts blinking..

I have installed lammps-daily by using this [link](http://lammps.sandia.gov/download.html#ubuntu).

Could somebody please help me how to come out of this..
Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I got it..
We need to just include at the end of .bashrc
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4

After this, the warning disappears.
Here, 4 corresponds to no. of cores in the system.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Pilot6 this is the OP posting his own answer...

Answer (score 1):

> WARNING: OMP_NUM_THREADS environment is not set. (../comm.cpp:100)
> using 1 OpenMP thread(s) per MPI task

Environment is not set!!

So your problem is here, you have to add the [environment variable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).

> [Environment Variable  OMP_NUM_THREADS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH4D_12.1.0/com.ibm.xlf121.aix.doc/proguide/ompthreads.html) sets the number of threads that a program will use when it runs.
>
> The syntax is as follows:
>
> > > OMP_NUM_THREADS= num
>
> **num** the maximum number of threads that can be used if dynamic
> adjustment of the number of threads is enabled.

**Note:** If the number of threads you request exceeds the number your execution environment can support, your application will terminate.

So to add this variable, so what you done:

Add this line to your `.bashrc`:

```
export  OMP_NUM_THREADS=NUM
```

Replace NUM  with your max thread number